# Firestore where statement with array-containts doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I check my database for a reference (which exists) and i don't get any chats back but I don't see where.

**chat.service.ts:**

```
  getUserChats(): Observable<Chat[]> {
        let uid = '-1';
        this.auth.currUser.subscribe(user => (uid = user.uid));
        this.chats = this.afs
          .collection('chats', ref => ref.where('members', 'array-contains', `users/${uid}`))
          .snapshotChanges()
          .pipe(
            map(actions => {
              return actions.map(action => {
                const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Chat;
                const id = action.payload.doc.id;
                return {id, ...data};
              });
            })
          ) as Observable<Chat[]>;
        return this.chats;
      }
```

The code is intented to get all the chats where the logged in user is a member in. I do this by checking the members array, if there is any reference to him.

**chat.component.ts:**

```
chats: Observable<Chat[]>;
  constructor(private router: Router, public chatService: ChatService, public dialog: MatDialog, public auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.chats = this.chatService.getUserChats();
  }
```

**chat.component.html:**

```
<mat-list-option *ngFor="let chat of chats | async" (click)="handleClick(chatList)" [value]="chat.id">
        <img matListAvatar src="./assets/avatar.svg" alt="Avatar Icon">
        <h3 mat-line>{{chat.name}}</h3>
        <p mat-line>test</p>
      </mat-list-option>
```

**Chat structure:**

[image: model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value '-1' will be searched for instantly because I'm not waiting for the User Observable to finish, that's why it searchs for -1 and finds nothing, so I have to wait for the user Observable. Still don't know how to return the inner observable then.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you are querying for `users/uid` while it is `/users/uid` that is stored in your database, see the first /

Comment: FYI, I've just made some tests and slashes (/) in the array value do not create any problem (I suspected that maybe the / were the problem cause... but no). If I test your database model and values with a "pure" javascript code the query works well.

Answer (score 0):

i think that you return "this.chat" from the service before the Observable comeback from the server . 
you need to return the Observable himself....
try this change:

```
getUserChats(): Observable < Chat[] > {
    let uid = '-1';
    this.auth.currUser.subscribe(user => (
            uid = user.uid;

            //that what you need to return
            return this.afs
                .collection('chats', ref => ref.where('members', 'array- 
                        contains ', `users/${uid}`))
                        .snapshotChanges()
                        .pipe(
                            map(actions => {
                                return actions.map(action => {
                                    const data = action.payload.doc.data() as Chat;
                                    const id = action.payload.doc.id;
                                    return { id,...data   };
                                });
                            })
                        ) as Observable < Chat[] > ;

                    }

                ));
```

each Observable need subscribe - but in angular the async pipe make it for you - so you just need to pass him Observable.

i edit my answer - now the query waits to the answer from the user auth

Comment: I don't want to subscribe, I want to get the Observable as a return value @yehonatan yehezkel

Comment: i think that you the rxjs operator switchMap will solve your problem.
https://youtu.be/65Us8NwmYf4?t=242